# SequenceInputStream not merge audio file

Tags: android, audio

I want to create voice recorder approx functionality is completed but, I need to implement Pause and resume functionality for this feature I need to merge my two audio file but I'm not able to get exact result. I've used sequence input stream but this merge only first file 
this is my code

```
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(mergeFile.get(0));
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(mergeFile.get(1));

        Vector<FileInputStream> v = new Vector<FileInputStream>();
        v.add(fis1);
        v.add(fis2);
        Enumeration<FileInputStream> e = v.elements();
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, "Test");
        file.mkdir();

        // InputStream inputStream1 = new FileInputStream(recording1);
        // InputStream inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(recording2);

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        SequenceInputStream sistream = new SequenceInputStream(e);
        FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(file
                + "/myfile.mp3");

        int temp = 0;
        while ((temp = sistream.read()) != -1) {
            // System.out.print( (char) temp ); // to print at DOS prompt
            fostream.write(temp); // to write to file
        }

        fostream.close();
        sistream.close();
        // recording1.close();
        // r/ecording2.close();
    }
```

when I play the final result, it plays only first file.

Comment: The problem is not the code, but the assumption that you can join two mp3 streams by joining their content like this.

Comment: I had issues when playing SequenceInputStream in the browser of files  with different sample rates (e.g. one 44100Hz and the other different) and also when the two of them have different amount of channels (e.g. one uses one channel only and the other 2).

Answer (score 1):

Use this merger code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Merger
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
    System.out.println("enter the filename");
    int a,no,i,j=1;
    String str,start;
    int ch;
    Console c=System.console();
    str=c.readLine();
    System.out.println("enter the destination file size");
    start=c.readLine();
    a=Integer.parseInt(start);


    File fr=new File(j+str);
    if(!fr.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream((str));
    for(i=0,j=1;    ;)
    {
        FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream(j+str);


        for(i=0;   (ch=f.read())!=-1  ;++i)
        fos.write(ch);
        j++;
            File fq=new File(j+str);
        if(!(fq).exists())
        {
            System.out.println("process completed");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    }
}
```

for this you need to convert your mp3 file in to input stream & add this input stream with second one input stream. this code for text file you can use this for audio file also.